# Easy Mysql query. 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to obtain all the orders in which appear a pair of products.

I have a table like with id_order   id_line (key)   id_product

i'm using 
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_order) FROM table WHERE id_product = i` to know in how many orders appear one product, but i don't know how to ask for a pair of them.

Thank you all in advance,

I hope that is clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a second table with order lines

```
SELECT id_product, id_order FROM order_table AS ot
INNER JOIN product_table AS pt1 ON ot.id_order=pt1.id_order AND pt1.id_product=i
INNER JOIN product_table AS pt2 ON ot.id_order=pt2.id_order AND pt2.id_product=j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_product, count(distinct id_order)
from table
where id_product in (i, j)
group by id_product
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately this is not working :(

Comment: When providing sample code or SQL please add explanations